# Manual authentication respecting filters with Spring Security

Tags: authentication, spring-security

### Hello,

In my application I have two ways to log in:

1. Log in on external IDP using OpenSAML. On callback (defined POST mapping) I'm reading the data from Assertion and then I authenticate the user
2. "Demo" login - user clicks on the button and the website automatically logs in the user using hardcoded credentials

## Current implementation

GET mapping (for demo login), POST mapping for OpenSAML login executes the

```
Authentication authentication = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(user, null, authorities);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

They both construct the `user` variable differently (one from SAML Assertion, another is hard coded). It "kinda" works (the user **is** authenticated), but there's one big issue preventing me from calling it a day.

## The issue

My Spring Security config:

```
    http.sessionManagement()
        .enableSessionUrlRewriting(true)
        .maximumSessions(1)
        .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
```

does not work properly (Spring's `SessionManagementFilter` does not run

```
// The user has been authenticated during the current request, so call the
// session strategy
try {
    this.sessionAuthenticationStrategy.onAuthentication(authentication, request, response);
}
```

because I manually set the `authentication` in `SecurityContext`

## Expected behavior

I'm authenticating an user (manually? I need the "demo" login to work as well) in a way that respects Spring Security filters and prevents double log in (maximumSessions = 1 works in `SessionManagementFilter`).

## "Workaround"

I've been able to make this work if I define manually `ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy` and use it in current implementation

```
Authentication authentication = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(user, null, authorities);
sessionAuthenticationStrategy.onAuthentication(authentication, request, response);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

I don't like it though because Spring uses internally `CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy` and  `ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy` is just one of them.

Kind regards,
Marcin